# What to do when a new employer ask you to create them a new book of business

Tags: new-job, new-hires

So I recently accepted a new job and put in my leaving notice for my current employment. Half way through my two week notice, my team lead from my new employment wants me to give them a list at least 20 leads from family friends and/or professional relationships I have created. Unfortunately, most of my friends and family are either not interested after reaching out or just do not fit the criteria for the leads they want. I am also fairly new in my field of work so although I have already tried to do a lot of networking this week, I am still coming up short. I am afraid that this may be a condition of my employment at my new job and that I might have to stay with my current employment even now after putting in my two week notice. Has anyone else been in this situation. I feel stumped.

Comment: Why are you working for them when you haven't finished your notice yet?

Comment: I don’t understand the situation..you’re supposed to find them 20 people to hire?

Comment: @morbo 20 people to target with marketing... bombard with phone calls, pester by email etc etc

Comment: Leads? Is this a multilevel marketing business by chance? Is it too late to get your old job back?

Comment: Or is this a law firm?

Comment: This is an Insurance Agency. We offer voluntary group benefits and exactly, I have not worked a single day there yet. I am finishing out my last week at my current job.

Comment: "I have not worked a single day there yet."  I and others would suggest otherwise.  You're not even there yet and yet they are already asking you to drum up business for them.  To me that is a really big red flag.

Comment: It sounds like one of the major things they hope to get out of you as an employee is contact info for your friends and family.  "Sell us your social connections" is never going to be a good deal for you as a person, and if their gain from you is that front-loaded, they probably won't hang on to you all that long after they've drained you of it.  Heck - for right now, it sounds like they're trying to get the list even before the hire.  It's possible (not likely, but possible) that if you give them the list before your start date, they'll not bother to hire you at all .

Answer (score 19):

> What to do when a new employer ask you to create them a new book of business

You wait until your notice period at your current company has ended and begin working on gathering the leads when you actually start working for the new company.  If your new company finds this arrangement unacceptable then I would seriously reconsider joining this company.

Assuming you decide to stick with the new company, if you value the relationships that you have with your family, friends, and former coworkers I would avoid using them as leads.

Answer (score 6):

This is an absolute red flag. Your family and friends are *not* leads. Your professional contacts are *not* leads.

Go to your old manager, tell them what you are asked to do, and ask if you can keep your job. From personal experience, some co- worker left, started a new job 9am on Monday, called at 9:10am if he could have his job back, his manager said “yes” and HR removed any documentation that he was ever gone.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere both answers say family & friends are not leads... And **I** would not do that to my friends... Would you? really?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere if you have reason to think that this is normal and acceptable behavior, then you could write an answer to that effect.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere then you could express *that*, and perhaps some pertinent advice on how to handle it.  I'm just saying that you seem to have pertinent understanding here taht the other answers lack.